# Declarative Workflow : Get User properties

Tags: 2013, workflow, workflow-activity, state-machine

I am using SharePoint 2013. I am reading a row in a SP list based on a field value I need to send to the Manager of that particular item. In the list there is a field as "Manager" which is People type column.

I am using Visual studio to create my declarative workflow (wf is SP 2013). How can I do this using the actions which are available when creating a workflow.

1) I am currently using a "HttpSend" Control where it sends a REST call and gets the value in the item for the 'People' field as:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items?$select=Manager&$filter=Id eq '1'
```

2) Then assign the returned value to a variable using "GetDynamicValueProperties" Control as below

```
d/results(0)/ManagerId
```

3) Then I use a "LookupSPUser" control to get user details.(What i really need is the user login name in-order to send a mail)

But the problem is I supply the Id which a got in step 2 as the principal id

I also saw in a article that you can use a REST call to people manager (`_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties`) but it didn't elaborate on how to get a target users details

Whats the best way to get the Login Name which corresponds to a People field in SP List item ?

Answer (score 1):

to get Login name use this

```
_api/Web/currentuser/Title
```

hope it can help you